# Calculated field in access with a loop

Tags: ms-access

I want to use a calculated field in access, however, the tricky part for me is when I have to run it through the dates. I have a database with multiple registers for the same day, but with different dates. Let's take this one for example:

```
Date | Report | Onblock Time
-----|--------|-------------
27/5 |   5:45 |         8:52
-----|--------|-------------
27/5 |   9:35 |        10:57
-----|--------|-------------
27/5 |  11:52 |        12:59
```

So, what I want to do is add 45 minutes to the first time that shows (in this case 5:45) and add 30 minutes to the last one (in this case 12:59). Once those two things are done, I want to calculate the difference between them.

I've tried `[(Onblock Time + 0:30) - (Report - 0:45)]` in the expression generator, and it seems to work. The problem I have is when I have to make it for a table that has 1000's of registers, with 4-6 a day. Is there any sort of automated loop, like a `for each` of anything like that?

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Comment: No, there is no 'automated loop' available in query. Not really clear what you want. Do you want the first and last records for each register for each day? You say you want to add minutes but you show subtracting 0:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you need a query, which returns for each day number of minutes between minimum of `ReportTime` + 0:45 and maximum of `OnblockTime` + 0:30. If so, the SQL for query should be like this:

```
SELECT ReportDate
    ,DateDiff("n", DateAdd("n", 45, Min([ReportTime])), DateAdd("n", 30, Max([OnblockTime]))) AS Diff
FROM TimeTable
GROUP BY ReportDate;
```